# How to get a single House price from a trained RandomForest model based on Input provided

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I have defined a random forest model, split the data into training and testing, Trained the model using `trainx` and `trainy` and my targeted variable i.e y =  price. when I run `df_model.predict(valx)`. It returns me with an array which contains Predicted Prices.
Now what I want is user enter the house of size 3BHK, location US, area_type superbuiltin and He get the price of "Single house" 
Instead of that numpy array, I want O/P as mentioned above.

I tried using `df_model.predict(df.Landsize)` and It gives me prediction of landsizes but I want prices
MY code is Shared below

```
  df=pd.read_csv('house_data.csv')
  df_feautres=['Rooms','Balcony','Bathroom','Landsize','Lattitude','Longtitude']
  x=df[df_feautres]
  y=df.Price
  df_model=RandomForestRegressor(random_state=1)
  train_x,val_x,train_y,val_y=train_test_split(x,y,random_state=1)
  df_model.fit(x,y)
  prediction=df_model.predict(val_x)
  print(prediction)
```

I'm getting a Numpy array of Predicted Prices but I want a price of Single house based on user Input

Comment: Could you provide an example of your data?

Comment: Address    Rooms  Price  Balcony  Bathroom  Landsize  Lattitude  Longtitude
0   paloura      3   52.0        1         2    1000.0  32.749944   74.824387
1     Jammu      3   75.0        1         3    2100.0  32.731253   74.863586
2     Jammu      9  210.0        1         4    2330.0  32.731253   74.863586
3     Jammu      1   50.0        1         1    1000.0  32.731253   74.863586
4  Bathindi      4   68.0        1         4    2000.0  32.710410   74.906224

Comment: provide data by editing the question not in comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would to like to answer my own Question.
I get the input from user and stored them into dictionary and then created a DataFrame from dictionary like df=pd.DataFrame(d)
and then passed this DF as input to predict Price like
 df_model.predict(df)